# How to convert big endian vector<char> to uint_64 c++

Tags: c++

How do i convert a vector of chars to a unsigned int 64?

```
std::vector<char> bytes = {0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,
                           0x0b,0x52,0xed,0xfb,0x9f,0x29,0x80,0x00}

qint64 wall_clock = (bytes.at(10) << 56 & 0xFF00000000000000) |
                    (bytes.at(11) << 48 & 0x00FF000000000000) |
                    (bytes.at(12) << 40 & 0x0000FF0000000000) |
                    (bytes.at(13) << 32 & 0x000000FF00000000) |
                    (bytes.at(14) << 24 & 0x00000000FF000000) |
                    (bytes.at(15) << 16 & 0x0000000000FF0000) |
                    (bytes.at(16) << 8  & 0x000000000000FF00) |
                    (bytes.at(17)       & 0x00000000000000FF);
```

I keep getting       `0xFFFF9F298000`.
the result should be `0x0B52EDFB9F298000`.

what am i missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The shift operator promotes `char` to a 32-bit `int` (with sign extension on platforms with signed plain `char`) and shifting it beyond 31 bit is undefined behaviour.

You need to cast `char` to `unsigned char` first to avoid the sign extension, then cast it to `uint64_t` and only then do the shift:

```
static_cast<uint64_t>(static_cast<unsigned char>(bytes.at(10))) << 56
```

---

Alternatively, just reverse copy it:

```
uint64_t load_bigendian(void const* bytes) {
    uint64_t result;
    std::copy(
        static_cast<unsigned char const*>(bytes),
        static_cast<unsigned char const*>(bytes) + sizeof result,
        std::reverse_iterator<unsigned char*>(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&result + 1))
        );
    return result;
}
```

[On x86_64 it generates](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/IwVlHT) one [`movbe`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/movbe) instruction - cannot get more efficient than that:

> The `MOVBE` instruction is provided for swapping the bytes on a read from memory or on a write to memory; thus providing support for converting little-endian values to big-endian format and vice versa.